# How to join two queries in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In this example, I am using the sample [MySQL classicmodels database](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx).

So I have two queries:

```
products = session.query(Products)
orderdetails = session.query(OrderDetails)
```

**Let's assume I cannot make any more queries to the database after this and I can only join these two queries from this point on.**

I want to do an outer join on them to be able to do something like this:

```
for orderdetail, product in query:
    print product.productName, product.productCode, orderdetails.quantityOrdered
```

However, whenever I do an outerjoin on this, I can only seem to get a left join.

```
query = orderdetails.outerjoin(Products)
```

Code like this yields only orderdetails columns:

```
for q in query:
    # Only gives orderdetails columns
    print q
```

And doing something like this:

```
for orderdetails, product in query:
    print orderdetails, product
```

Gives me an error: `TypeError: 'OrderDetails' object is not iterable`.

What am I doing wrong? I just want columns from the Products table as well.

EDIT:

I have found my solution thanks to @univerio's answer. My real goal was to do a join on two existing queries and then do a `SUM` and `COUNT` operation on them.

SQLAlchemy basically just transforms a query object to a SQL statement. The `with_entities` function just changes the `SELECT` expression to whatever you pass to it. This is my updated solution, which includes unpacking and reading the join:

```
for productCode, numOrders, quantityOrdered in orderdetails.with_entities(
        OrderDetails.productCode, 
        func.count(OrderDetails.productCode),
        func.sum(OrderDetails.quantityOrdered)).group_by(OrderDetails.productCode):
    print productCode, numOrders, quantityOrdered
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite the entity list with [`with_entities()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/query.html?highlight=with_entities#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities):

```
orderdetails.outerjoin(Products).with_entities(OrderDetails, Products)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know there's a way to do it through session.query but is there a way to do it with the two session queries I have?

Comment: @joshualan I'm not sure I understand why you need to do that. No SQL is execute until you iterate through the query. Or did you want to join two subqueries? Or, you want to re-use an existing query because you have filters on it already?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to re-use those existing queries. It doesn't seem like there's a way though.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed, I've updated my question with the answer.